# ACK seq number and number of retransmission

Tags: networking, tcp

[image]

In the above *TCP stream*, I notice that the expected next seq number of no.9 TCP packet is *1902*. But the following ack number of the ACK packet is *1903*, which is 1 more than 1902.

I'm wondering whether it is due to the retransmission (No.9 is a retramsmission of N0.8?) if so, then if there are N retransmission, the ack number is seq+N? if not, what are the causes for the inconsistency?

Comment: Selective ACKs or block ACKs. And implicit ACKs.

Answer (score 0):

In TCP when you get an ACK, It points to *the next* packet your client is waiting to receive (i.e. last received byte + *1* ).
It's Just the way it is.

Edit: FIN and SYN both occupy one byte in the sequence. this could be the cause as well.